# Content hiding under Sticky Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Here is the URL of my website (https://hwrmedia.com.au/).When I scroll down to the HWR Publications section and click on any post of that section, It goes to particular post on another page, hiding the content under the sticky navbar. For this I have used this js code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      if (window.location.hash == "#moreInfo") {
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $("#moreInfo").offset().top-100
         }, 1000);
      }
   });
```

Comment: You need to adjust your offset.

Comment: offset is not making any difference :(

Comment: You can just add padding as the header height to the element you want to jump to..

Answer (score 1):

just add this jQuery Code

```
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top-100
 }, 1000);
```